# Bash Script to convert date format

Tags: bash

I'm looking to replace the exiting date format (`CCYY-MM-DD`) with `MM-DD-CCYY` date format in a large file using shell script. Before changing the date format, it should look like:

```
2014-01-31|2014-01-31|
```

And after change the date format should it look like:

```
01-31-2014|01-31-2014|
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using sed you can do it:

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/\2-\3-\1/g' file
```