# Convert all date fields in a record from yyyy-mm-dd to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: bash

How to covert all date fields in a record to convert from YYYY-MM-DD with MM/DD/YYYY.

Example Before change

```
2014-01-31|2014-01-31|A12345|1|Service|2|Service Transactions|1|Service|EMP|727123.57|727123.57|9543.67|9543.67|286.31|286.31|.00|2014-02-11 16:08:28|BIP|1|.00|1
```

Example after change

```
01/31/2014|01/31/2014|A12345|1|Service|2|Service Transactions|1|Service|EMP|727123.57|727123.57|9543.67|9543.67|286.31|286.31|.00|11/02/2014 16:08:28|BIP|1|.00|1
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: But you got the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996130/bash-script-to-convert-date-format/21996201#21996201

Comment: This one is different. I want convert from  yyyy-mm-dd to mm/dd/yyyy and this record has timestamp field(2014-02-11 16:08:28) needs that needs to convert(02/11/2014 16:08:28)  format along with time.

Comment: I'm trying to replace with - with / but it didn't work. How to replace with - with /

Comment: @user3347931 Change the separator in the solution anubhava provided you before. `sed -r 's_([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})_\2/\3/\1_g' file`.

Comment: Consider carefully whether doing this is a good idea. The `YYYY-MM-DD` format is an [ISO standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), it's unambiguous, and it sorts correctly. `MM/DD/YYYY` (popular in the US) does not sort easily and is easily confused with `DD/MM/YYYY` (popular in the UK). [Relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use below:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' file
```